# InputStream in Jersey REST only returns a single byte

Tags: java, rest, post, curl, jersey

I'm adding a new function to a server that uses jersey REST.  I want to post the data as binary.  I've simply added:

```
@POST
@Path('/mypath')
public void Foo(@QueryParam("var"), InputStream is) {
    int data[8];
    data[0] = is.read();
    data[1] = is.read();
}
```

Then I run the following command:

```
cat test.bin | curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:image/jpeg' -d @- http://localhost:8080/path/mypath?var=ok
```

When I step through the debugger the first byte is indeed the first byte of `test.bin`.  However, the second read returns -1 indicating that the stream has no more data.  Am I using `curl` incorrectly?  Is there some other setup for the provider that I need to do?  Other configuration params?  It seems that I don't need `@Consumes("*/*")` because it should be doing that by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, maybe you should be using `--data-binary` instead of `-d` (that is an alias for `--data-ascii`) for strictly binary data.

Also, instead of using the cat, you can use just `@test.bin` to include the file.

Using `curl` `-vv` parameter also helps showing what it is actually sent. It does not show the data, but at least it shows the `Content-Length` sent by `curl`.

Comment: I missed the --data-binary, which was indeed the problem. -vv is also very helpful, thx!